# Keycloak Gatekeeper Configuration Error "unable to exchange code for access token"

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, configuration, keycloak, access-token

I have a problem using keycloak gatekeeper for authorizing requests in a kubernetes cluster. A resource request is forwarded to login via keycloak, after login it is shown that access is forbidden using the gatekeepers forbidden page. The gatekeeper log looks like this:

```
{"level":"info","ts":1608128659.3984604,"msg":"keycloak proxy service starting","interface":":3000"}
{"level":"error","ts":1608128667.3914142,"msg":"no session found in request, redirecting for authorization","error":"authentication session not found"}
{"level":"info","ts":1608128667.3915262,"msg":"client request","latency":0.002089839,"status":307,"bytes":95,"client_ip":"192.168.42.129:48724","method":"GET","path":"/auth/"}
{"level":"info","ts":1608128667.4082289,"msg":"client request","latency":0.000065187,"status":307,"bytes":317,"client_ip":"192.168.42.129:48724","method":"GET","path":"/oauth/authorize"}

{"level":"error","ts":1608128671.970435,"msg":"unable to exchange code for access token","error":"unknown_error"}

{"level":"info","ts":1608128671.9705727,"msg":"client request","latency":0.203322612,"status":403,"bytes":2174,"client_ip":"192.168.42.129:48724","method":"GET","path":"/oauth/callback"}
```

I used a configuration similar to https://gist.github.com/carlosedp/80ea54104cc6303f04b3755033f9c4fe.

Is my redirect address maybe wrong, or is about the resource part in the configuration file?
The config file looks like this:

```
discovery-url: http://keycloak.192.168.42.129.nip.io/auth/realms/local/.well-known/openid-configuration
skip-openid-provider-tls-verify: true
client-id: gatekeeper
client-secret: XXX
listen: :3000
enable-refresh-tokens: true
tls-cert:
tls-private-key:
redirection-url: http://sb.192.168.42.129.nip.io
secure-cookie: false
encryption-key: XXX
upstream-url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/
forbidden-page: /html/access-forbidden.html
upstream-keepalives: true
skip-upstream-tls-verify: true
enable-logging: true
enable-json-logging: true
enable-encrypted-token: false
resources:
- uri: /*
```

Comment: I would say https is mandatory for OIDC, but you are using http. It can be a problem if used libraries expect https protocol only.

Comment: I was also thinking about this, but keycloak can be used with http and the service application (sb) itself is also communicationg to other services for now with http. The gatekeepers deyployment in the tutorial is also supporting this.

The config of upstream-url and redirection-url should be fine? What is the difference? The upstream is internal when I understand it right?